# "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" when listening for incoming data

Tags: c++, windows, networking, listener, boost-asio

When working with boost asio, I've stumbled upon some weird behavior, which I don't quite understand. I wrote a minimal test-program to replicate the problem:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    udp::resolver resolver(ioService);

    udp::resolver::query queryListen("127.0.0.1","50001");
    auto epListen = *resolver.resolve(queryListen);
    udp::socket socket(ioService,epListen);

    udp::resolver::query querySend("127.0.0.1","55006");
    auto epSend = *resolver.resolve(querySend);
    boost::system::error_code err;
    std::array<char,12> buffer = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'};
    socket.send_to(
        boost::asio::buffer(&buffer[0],buffer.size()),
        epSend,0,err
    );
    if(!err)
    {
        std::cout<<"Sent successfully!"<<std::endl;
        auto numBytes = socket.receive(
            boost::asio::buffer(&buffer[0],buffer.size()),0,
            err
        );
        if(!err)
            std::cout<<"Received "<<numBytes<<" bytes successfully!"<<std::endl;
        else
            std::cout<<"Unable to receive: "<<err.message()<<std::endl; // This is where I'm getting the message "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"
    }
    else
        std::cout<<"Unable to send: "<<err.message()<<std::endl;
    for(;;);
    return 0;
}
```

If the destination endpoint for the 'send_to'-call exists and is listening, this program runs just fine. The data is sent correctly, and it then waits for incoming data.

However, if the destination endpoint **doesn't** exist, the behavior is rather unexpected. The 'send_to'-call still dispatches the data without any errors, but when trying to receive data, the 'receive'-call immediately returns, and I'm getting a "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" error. This doesn't make any sense to me. First of all, **there is no remote host**, since there is no data being sent to the listener port. Secondly, from what I understand, the receiving- and the sending-part in this program should be completely independent, and shouldn't affect each other at all. Am I wrong in that assumption?

// Edit:

I've just realized that there's another reason why that message doesn't make any sense. I'm using the UDP procotol, which is connectionless, so what 'connection' was closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While UDP is often referred to as a connectionless protocol, the context implies a stateless protocol.  As such, [UDP](http://linux.die.net/man/7/udp) is permitted to return some connect-related error messages:

> All errors documented for [socket](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) or [ip](http://linux.die.net/man/7/ip) may be returned by a send or receive on a UDP socket.
>
> **ECONNREFUSED** 
>       No receiver was associated with the destination address. This might be caused by a *previous* packet sent over the socket.

The Winsock [`recvfrom()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740120(v=vs.85).aspx) function documents that for UDP, the function will error with `WSAECONNRESET` if a prior send operation resulted in an ICMP Port Unreachable message:

> **WSAECONNRESET** 
>       [...] On a UDP-datagram socket this error indicates a previous send operation resulted in an ICMP Port Unreachable message.