# Asio UDP socket receive failed

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

Tried this code to send/receive with Asio UDP sockets (boost less version)

```
asio::io_service service;
asio::ip::udp::socket sock(service);
asio::ip::udp::endpoint endpoint(asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 20100);

sock.connect(endpoint);
sock.send(buffer("testing\n"));

std::string buffer;
size_t length = sock.receive(asio::buffer(buffer)); <--- spawn exception
```

but got following error:

```
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Something wrong here? Thanks for any help!

Comment: @EJP It is possible -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224443/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host-when-listening-f

Comment: Can you please verify that there a UDP socket bound to port `20100`?  For a connected UDP socket, if there is no receiver at the destination address, after invoking `send()`, subsequent calls to `send()` and `receive()` may fail with `ECONNREFUSED`.

Comment: @TannerSansbury How can I verify this? (when I use TCP sockets I have no issues, but need to switch to UDP for reasons of speed)

Comment: Tools like netstat can be helpful in identifying if a port is open.  Both peers have to be using the same protocol.  Does the application to which you are trying to connect support UDP?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you build your udp server, but I guess something wrong with it. I write an example program to explain the error message you get:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <errno.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <string.h>  
#include <sys/types.h>  
#include <sys/socket.h>  
#include <netinet/in.h>  
#include <arpa/inet.h>  

int main()  
{    
    struct sockaddr_in addr;  
    int fd, cnt, ret;  

    if ((fd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {  
        printf("error");
        exit(1);  
    }

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));  
    addr.sin_family=AF_INET;  
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port=htons(9090); // address which is not bound

    ret = connect(fd,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(addr));  
    char buf[512];

    cnt =  send(fd, "hello", sizeof("hello"), 0);  
    if(cnt < 0)  
        perror("send:");  
    cnt = recv(fd, buf, 512, 0); // error: Connection refused
    if(cnt < 0)  
        perror("recv:");  

     return 0;  
}
```

I try to send data to udp port 9090 at localhost or any host which no udp socket is bound to port 9090. the `send()` succeeds but the `recv()` fails. According to [man page for udp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html):

> All fatal errors will be passed to the
>   user as an error return even when the
>   socket is not connected. This includes
>   asynchronous errors received from the
>   network. You may get an error for an
>   earlier packet that was sent on the
>   same socket. This behaviour differs
>   from many other BSD socket
>   implementations which don't pass any
>   errors unless the socket is connected.
>   Linux's behaviour is mandated by
>    According to the [rfc 1122](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1122.txt)

which says:

> UDP MUST pass to the application layer all ICMP error messages that it receives from the IP layer. Conceptually at least, this may be accomplished with an upcall to the ERROR_REPORT routine

the `send()` succeeds, but it causes an ICMP error message(you can see it with tcpdump), then `recv()` sees this error(**You may get an error for an earlier packet that was sent on the same socket**), so it fails.